# Is ‘Political gold’ a cliché or just a compound noun?

Tags: expressions

I found the word, ‘*political gold’* in the following sentence of the article of Boston News (August 13) titled “Romney sees gain in ‘Corporations are people’ remark.”

> “Romney's response that "corporations are people" to a liberal heckler during an exchange over fiscal policy at the Iowa State Fair immediately lit up the argument The Democratic National Committee jumped on the comment and saw its own *political gold* in trying to score points against a leading contender for the GOP nomination.”

As I was unfamiliar with the word, ‘Political gold,’ I checked Google and found a couple of examples of the word in use, e.g.

- Kathy Hochul found political gold in Paul Ryan plan. – Buffalo News May 25, 2011
- Belgian stalemate spun into political gold. - Financial Times – April 25, 2011

From the word “Romney sees gain in ‘Corporations are people’ " remark, I can easily guess ‘political gold’ means political gain, advantage or opportunity.

However I wonder whether political gold is a intertwined cliché (or idiom) or just a compound word of ‘political and gold’ that allows application to any other compounds like ‘business gold,’ ‘scientific gold,’ ‘cultural gold,’ or ‘technology gold.’

Comment: *[Comedy gold](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=comedy%20gold)* is a relative common, modern phrase that is similar in concept.  I believe the phrase was popularized by *Seinfeld*.

Answer (score 2):

It's both - you can certainly have ‘business gold,’ ‘scientific gold’ ‘cultural gold,’ or ‘technology gold'.

But if you use them too much they are a cliche

Answer (score 1):

Is this a cliche? Let's define [cliche:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cliche)

> a sentence or phrase, usually expressing a popular or common thought or idea, that has lost originality, ingenuity, and impact by long overuse,

Note, the phrase or term becomes a cliche *only if it has been overused*. Now, I doubt if "political gold" is overused, as I haven't heard it being used as much as some other [cliches](http://www.clichesite.com/index.asp) ("Cup of tea", etc.)

Thus, I would say it wasn't a cliche (yet), but it is definitely a compound noun.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's still a cliché.

I think you are referring to the following process:

1. A clever writer comes up with a fresh new expression or metaphor. (e.g. *When she goes on a date she isn't looking for love; she is digging for gold.*)
2. Other writers copy the metaphor.
3. The metaphor is used so widely it becomes a cliché. (*Those gold diggers....*)
4. The cliché becomes so well-worn speakers use it without necessarily referring to the original metaphor.  It becomes an idiom.
5. The idiom becomes a compound word. ("*gold-digger*")

In my opinion, *political gold* is still at stage 3; it still has some way to go before it reaches stage 5.  However, I suspect that *political gold* probably derives from the idiom *struck [political / comedy / technological / ...] gold*, so it is a cliché derived from an idiom.